# Java - ScriptEngineManager nashorn Math.random does not work

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

i call the follow function with the functionName "random" and the parameter "1 and 50".

```
private String callFunction(String functionName, String[] parameter)
            throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {

        ScriptEngineManager engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.eval(new FileReader(myPath + functionName + ".js"));
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        Object result;
        if (parameter == null) {
            result = invocable.invokeFunction(functionName);
        } else {
            result = invocable.invokeFunction(functionName, parameter);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return (String) result;
    }
```

The content of random.js looks like:

```
  function random(min, max){
    return  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
  }
```

The results are never between 1 and 50. It is always more than 100.

If i use it not in java it works.
Work math from nashorn/javascript oherwise in java?

**UPDATE**:

My solution is:

```
private String callFunction(String functionName, String parameter)
        throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassCastException {
    String result = "";
    engine.eval(new FileReader(PropertiesHandler.getFullDynamicValuePath() + functionName + ".js"));

    if (parameter == null) {
        result = (String) engine.eval(functionName + "();");
    } else {
        result = (String) engine.eval(functionName + parameter + ";");
    }
    return (String) result;
}
```

So i can use parameters with different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Elliot's example there must be something wrong with the parameters you are passing in.  The following also generates 100 values between 1 and 50.

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    String script = "function random(min, max) { "
            + "return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }";
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Invocable invocable = (Invocable)engine;
    try {
        engine.eval(script);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Double result = (Double)invocable.invokeFunction("random", 1, 50);
            System.out.println(result.intValue());
        }
    } catch (ScriptException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you have right! i have always use String parameters! I thought invokeFunction can use only Strings. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your example a little bit you can't assign a [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) to a [`ScriptEngineManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html) and it's unclear how you're displaying your random values, or how you're calling `random`. However, this generates 100 random values between `1` and `50` here

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    String script = "function random(min, max) { "
            + "return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }";
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
        engine.eval(script);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            engine.eval("print(random(1, 50));");
        }
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! With the invokeFunction does not work it, but with your solution it works like a charm! With the assign a ScriptEngine to a ScriptEngineManager was a typing mistake for this posting. The user of my programm can use his own javascript that's why i try it with random.

Comment: I need 4 more Flag posts than can i vote for your post ;)